# How to replicate histograms from ggplot code

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code using `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(sub9, aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,15),expand=c(0, 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  xlab(" ") + ylab("No of papers") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=13)) +
  annotate("text",x=3.5,y=14,label="Pollution",cex=7)
```

I have 25 plots like this, and need to plot many plots within the same graph page. This usually works well in R, using e.g. `par(mfrow=c(4,4))` for a 4 x 4 plot. This code doesn't work with ggplot, where I have to use the function `multiplot`, which doesn't work that well as it doesn't scale all the text and legends accordingly.

Therefore I ask if some of you out there could help me replicate the exact same plot using `hist`.The x (YR) is a factor, and the y (Freq) is numerical.

Comment: Instead of using that `multiplot` function, it is probably better to use `grid.arrange` of the `gridExtra` package which is specifically designed for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're asking for putting multiple ggplots on the same page or asking for how to run histogram.

Anyway, here's an example of histogram with iris data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5)
```

I'd used grid.arrange to create a 3x2 layout of 6 replicated plots:

```
grid.arrange (g1, g1, g1, g1, g1, g1, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it seems as `grid.arrange` gives the same output as `multiplot` i.e. no scaling of text within the plot.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid`

You might be looking for [facet_wrap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html) or [facet_grid](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html), which allow you to create multiple plots for different values of a factor or other categorical variable. Of course this also works for histograms.

### Example from documentation

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)
```

[image: example facet grid]